# Print special characters

Tags: python, printing, character, percentage

How can I print out the character "%" in the print function. The following line fails.

```
print "The result is %s out of %s i.e. %d %" % (nominator, denominator, percentage)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must escape the `%` by doing `%%`. So in your example, do:

```
print "The result is %s out of %s i.e. %d %%" % (nominator, denominator, percentage)
#                                         ^ extra % to escape the one after
```

Comment: @SteveP. I actually have no clue, I guess it's just `%` to escape `%` and `\\` for apostrophes

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

```
>>> n=23.2
>>> d=1550
>>> "The result is {:.2f} out of {:.2f} i.e. {:.2%}".format(n,d,n/d)
'The result is 23.20 out of 1550.00 i.e. 1.50%'


>>> "The result is {:,.2f} out of {:,.2f} i.e. {:.2%}".format(n,d,n/d)
'The result is 23.20 out of 1,550.00 i.e. 1.50%'
```

If your arguments are strings:

```
>>> "The result is {:,.2f} out of {} i.e. {:.2%}".format(n,str(d),n/d)
'The result is 23.20 out of 1550 i.e. 1.50%'
```