# Why can't a backslash be used to escape a percentage character when using the interpolation operator

Tags: python

As stated in the title, why doesn't this work:

```
print "Hello, my name is %s, I am %d\% confused!" % ("steve", 100)
```

I know the solution is to use `%%` to represent a raw `%`, but why doesn't the `\%` work when using the interpolation operator?  I assume this wasn't some random design decision, and of course `\` still escapes when using the interpolation operator, as in:

```
print "Hello, my name is %s\n, I am %d%% confused!" % ("steve", 100)
```

prints:

> Hello, my name is steve,
>  I am 100% confused!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a "random" design decision. [`\n` is a standard C escape sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C); the `%` for string formatting is not. Using `%` instead of `\` to escape `%` reinforces that distinction.

Furthermore, [Python's `%` string formatting (deprecated in Python 3.1) is based on C's `sprintf`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting), which is where the `%%` syntax to print a literal `%` originated. **Note that this is not an escape sequence.** The first `%` does not escape the second one here! As with all the other conversion specifications, the first `%` introduces the conversion specifier, and the second `%` is the conversion specifier.

See [your friendly neighborhood `man sprintf` pages](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf) for more.

Comment: [Well then, I guess I was wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19738739/print-special-characters/19738743#19738743). Learn something new every day :)

Answer (score 2):

Escaping with `\` is for the parser, it does its job before the string object is created, `'\x5cn'` won't make a new line. While `%` is for the formater after the object is created, `'\x25s' % 'n'` is fine.

If `\%` is used, how should `\%` be escaped?, `\\%` or `\%%` won't work, using `\\%%` is just worst, the simplest solution is that the special character escapes itself, there are other techniques to escape, read here [Delimiter collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal#Delimiter_collision).

Comment: @SteveP. `\\%%` and `\\\%` look uglier than `%%`.